# Why is the blur event listener fired twice for the same element with contenteditable in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom-events

This is the code, which I reduced and simplified as much as I could:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const parentElementRef = useRef();
  const childElementRef = useRef();
  const [focusedElement, setFocusedElement] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const clickEventListener = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      setFocusedElement(event.currentTarget);
      console.log('click');
      console.log(event.target === childElementRef.current);
      console.log(event.currentTarget === childElementRef.current);
    };

    const blurEventListener = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('blur');
      console.log(event.target === childElementRef.current);
      console.log(event.currentTarget === childElementRef.current);
    };

    parentElementRef.current.addEventListener('click', clickEventListener);
    parentElementRef.current.addEventListener('blur', blurEventListener);

    childElementRef.current.addEventListener('click', clickEventListener);
    childElementRef.current.addEventListener('blur', blurEventListener);

    return () => {
      childElementRef.current.removeEventListener('click', clickEventListener);
      childElementRef.current.removeEventListener('blur', blurEventListener);

      parentElementRef.current.removeEventListener('click', clickEventListener);
      parentElementRef.current.removeEventListener('blur', blurEventListener);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    focusedElement?.focus();
  }, [focusedElement]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={parentElementRef}
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      }}
    >
      <div
        ref={childElementRef}
        contentEditable={focusedElement === childElementRef.current}
        suppressContentEditableWarning
        style={{
          width: '200px',
          height: '200px',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}
      >
        Hello world!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is a StackBlitz link to try it out:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-pibe1s?file=src%2FApp.jsx

If you click on the 'Hello world!' text and then on the green space, you will get this output:

```
click
true
true
blur
true
true
click
false
false
blur
true
true
```

If you click on the red square, **BUT NOT** in the 'Hello world!' text, you get this output:

```
click
true
true
blur
true
true
click
false
false
```

If you remove `display: 'flex'` from the parent element, you will always get the same output no matter where you click on the red box.

I just want to understand this behavior. Why does it even matter if I have `display: 'flex'` or not in the parent, and when it has it, why does clicking in the text make any difference in how many times the blur event is executed?

---

**Desired behavior:**

The code should output this in the console when interacted as specified, which is what I would expect:

```
click
true
true
blur
true
true
click
false
false
```

**Specific problem or error:**

I get this output instead and I'd like to understand why:

```
click
true
true
blur
true
true
click
false
false
blur
true
true
```

**Shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem:**

This is the code I just posted at the beginning of this post.

Comment: Someone voted to close this question with "Needs debugging details", so I edited my post before it gets closed to make it dead obvious in case it wasn't clear enough already what the desired behavior, the specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem are.